# Help with selection via calculation without if-statements

Tags: c

### Problem

Given the length of the three axes that comprise an ellipsoid calculate the volume of the object and determine
whether the shape is a spheroid (D), sphere (P), or a scalene ellipsoid (C).

- A spheroid consists of two of three axes that share the same length.
- In a sphere all three axes will be of the same length.
- A scalene ellipsoid has no two axes of the same length.

The use of selection, including logical and relational operators, is prohibited.

Here is my code so far:

```
*/
#include<stdio.h>
#define PI 3.1416

int main (void)
{
  //Local Declarations
  double axis1;
  double axis2;
  double axis3;
  double Vellipsoid;
  int factor;


  //Statements
  printf("Enter the length of all three axes: ");
  scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &axis1, &axis2, &axis3);
  Vellipsoid = ( 4 * PI * axis1 * axis2 * axis3 ) / 3;



  printf("\nObject volume: %10.2lf \n ", Vellipsoid);
  printf("Object Shape: ");

 return 0;
} //main
```

### Question

I need help coding a way to display the following executions:

Example Output #1 (shape is a spheroid):
Enter the lengths of all three axes: 10 5 10
Object volume: 2094.40
Object Shape: D

Example Output #2 (shape is a sphere):
Enter the lengths of all three axes: 7 7 7
Object volume: 1436.76
Object Shape: P

Example Output #3 (shape is a scalene ellipsoid):
Enter the lengths of all three axes: 9 4 6
Object volume: 904.78
Object Shape: C

How would I be able to code this so that I can make those characters appear for the designations of types shapes.

Any ideas/examples would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered a case statement?

Comment: Julia, I've reformatted your question.  If the reformatting isn't what you intended, let us know...

Answer (score 0):

Since logical (`&&`, `||`, `!`) and relational (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`) operators are out, and I presume bitwise is also not allowed, that leaves pure equality: `==`.

You can begin by defining some metrics for these cases using math.  Let's say your axes are called A, B, C.  You can determine:

- Sphere : `A - B` and `B - C` are zero.
- Spheroid : Exactly one of `A - B`, `B - C` or `C - A` is zero.
- Scalene : Each of `A - B`, `B - C` or `C - A` is non-zero.

So you could code this as follows:

```
int abz = (axis1 - axis2) == 0.0;
int bcz = (axis2 - axis3) == 0.0;
int caz = (axis3 - axis1) == 0.0;
int is_sphere = (abz + bcz) == 2;
int is_spheroid = (abz + bcz + caz) == 1;
int is_scalene = (abz + bcz + caz) == 0;
```

Notice how `is_sphere`, `is_spheroid` and `is_scalene` are all based on different values for (almost) the same calculation: With the exception of `is_sphere`, we're always using `abz + bcz + caz`.  So let's change it to use the same calculation:

```
int is_sphere = (abz + bcz + caz) == 3;
```

Now, you're not allowed selection either, so case statements and if-statements are out.  And so you don't even need the `is_XXXX` values (they were just to illustrate).  Instead, you can use an array:

```
char shape[4] = { 'C', 'D', '?', 'P' };
printf( "Shape: %c\n", shape[abz+bcz+caz] );
```

Note that the 3rd value `'?'` is actually not possible because of the transitive property of equality.

Of course, this is still needlessly complicated.  We're already using equality.  Why bother subtracting?

```
int abz = (axis1 == axis2);
int bcz = (axis2 == axis3);
int caz = (axis3 == axis1);
```

I'll finish by recommending that you don't get into the habit of doing this type of branchless code unless absolutely necessary.  In industry, you only do it when you have a *legitimate* optimization requirement.  All other times, you should write code that is clear and easily understandable.